# Set Text of EditeText of Fragment from Activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragmentactivity, android-tablayout

How can I set the text of an EditText of an Fragment from the Activity?

Here es the Activity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    FrameLayout simpleFrameLayout;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    EditText editText;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        simpleFrameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);
        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);
// Create a new Tab named "First"
        TabLayout.Tab firstTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        firstTab.setText("Personal"); // set the Text for the first Tab
        tabLayout.addTab(firstTab); // add  the tab at in the TabLayout
// Create a new Tab named "Second"
        TabLayout.Tab secondTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        secondTab.setText("Chat"); // set the Text for the second Tab
        tabLayout.addTab(secondTab); // add  the tab  in the TabLayout
        
        
        
        try {
            Fragment fragment = null;
            fragment = new FirstFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
            ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
            ft.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
        
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
// get the current selected tab's position and replace the fragment accordingly
                    try {
                        Fragment fragment = null;
                    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
                        case 0:
                            fragment = new FirstFragment();
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            fragment = new SecondFragment();
                            break;
                    }
                        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, fragment);
                    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
                        ft.commit();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
        
    }
    
    public void connect(){
        //set text of EditText of SecondFragment
    }
}
```

I am looking for a solution to this problem:
I want to create a chat client and for that I need to update the EditText of a tab from time to time without the need to switch to that tab. I also need the content of that EditText not to be lost when switching tabs.

Comment: If you don't want to lose the input, then why replace the fragment without keeping the previous one? Technically added fragments preserve their state, you're just removing them each time you switch a tab.

Comment: I don't know how to keep the old one :(

Comment: You need to add both fragments when `if(savedInstanceState == null) {` but keep one of them `fragmentTransaction.detach()`ed when it's not the one showing. Technically that's also how `FragmentPagerAdapter` works in a `ViewPager`. You find existing Fragment instance using `fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag()`.

Comment: If you keep getting answers saying "static EditText" (which is an anti-pattern), i might need to write a complete solution...

Comment: And how can I keep one of them fragmentTransaction.detach() by switching the tab?

Comment: Fair question, fair question demands a fair answer. I had to get home to write it.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable inside the main activity that you can update from the fragments. Since the activity's lifecycle doesn't change from one fragment to the other, you can then get the same value from the second fragment.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But what when switching tabs? The content of the one tab will be lost...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to use a `ViewPager` and a `PagerAdapter` (you don't need swiping between your tabs), this is what it should look like:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
    FrameLayout simpleFrameLayout;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    EditText editText;

    FirstFragment firstFragment;
    SecondFragment secondFragment;

    private int selectedTabIndex = 0;
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        
        simpleFrameLayout = findViewById(R.id.simpleFrameLayout);
        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.simpleTabLayout);

        TabLayout.Tab firstTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        firstTab.setText("Personal");
        tabLayout.addTab(firstTab);

        TabLayout.Tab secondTab = tabLayout.newTab();
        secondTab.setText("Chat");
        tabLayout.addTab(secondTab);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            firstFragment = new FirstFragment();
            secondFragment = new SecondFragment();

            fm.beginTransaction()
              .add(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, firstFragment, "firstFragment")
              .add(R.id.simpleFrameLayout, secondFragment, "secondFragment");
              .detach(secondFragment)
              .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
              .commitNow();
        } else {
            firstFragment = (FirstFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("firstFragment");    
            secondFragment = (SecondFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("secondFragment");

            this.selectedTabIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt("selectedTabIndex", 0);
            // selectTab(selectedTabIndex); // you don't need this line
        }
        
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                    this.selectedTabIndex = tab.getPosition();
                    selectTab(selectedTabIndex);
                }

                @Override
                public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

                }
            });
    }

    private void selectTab(int selectedTabIndex) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        if (selectedTabIndex == 0) {
            fm.beginTransaction()
              .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
              .detach(secondFragment)
              .attach(firstFragment)
              .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        } else if(selectedTabIndex == 1) {
            fm.beginTransaction()
              .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
              .detach(firstFragment)
              .attach(secondFragment)
              .commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
    
    public void connect(){
        secondFragment.updateText("someText"); // this can run when secondFragment has no view!
    }
}
```

Note: if you need to use more tabs, then you could use an array, but you'd still need to initialize / reinitialize as it is shown in this snippet.

Comment: Thank you for your collaboration. With your code I get some errors before running the app. Because of that I changed it a little bit. I tell you where it had errors and how the code looked like when it had errors: https://pastebin.com/6Gu36V6i. Then I show you the exception I get after the app runs without errors when I try to access Fragments View outside onCreateView method: https://pastebin.com/YtHyF5Bn

Comment: Huh. This is a project older than compileSdkVersion 26? Interesting. The view will only be there when the view is not detached, you need to check if the view is available, and set the value in a field. If the view is not available, then it will be in onCreateView and should be initialized from the field (and if the view is available then set it - `getView()` is the thingy)

Comment: Are the changes that I did in the code OK or wrong? And from what field should the view be initialized when it is not available? In the onCreateView method?

Comment: Create a String field in the Fragment. When that is updated, check if view is available. If yes, update the EditText as well. Set the field's value to the EditText in onCreateView. Persist the String value to onSaveInstanceState, and restore it in onCreate when `savedInstanceState != null`. Yes, this really is how fragments are intended to work, lol.

Comment: But when I restore a String value, that can contain thousand of words... At some point the app will become slower and slower if you have to load so much in a tab, right?

Comment: I don't know how much data there is in this string. If this is a chat app, you probably want to save drafts to disk anyway and not use savedInstanceState.

Comment: The most users who connect to chat connect only 10 minutes... Therefore, I do not know whether it is worth saving the chat history in the mobile phone. They also want to chat anonymously and privately.
I have found a way to communicate from MainActivity to Fragment: Bundle
But if I change the tab, the content of an EditText is lost. You can see the code: https://pastebin.com/N3eaq2hR

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room

Comment: Is this easier than trying to prevent a fragment to be unload?

Comment: Considering it sounds like you should remember stuff évek if the app is closed and then reopened, persistent storage sounds like what you want.

Answer (score -1):

A general answer based on your general question Make your edittext public static `public static EditText editText;`
Assign a value to it then call it like `MainActivity.editText.setText("");` from any other class
`
Use this approach only if its absolutely necessary as it may lead to memory leaks since you will have to manually destroy/nullify your object after use

Comment: No, you're not supposed to do that at all. It is an anti-pattern in Android development.

Comment: i agree.memory leaks if static views are mismanaged /not destroyed just edited to make it clear that this is just a way to do it.